# Better solution using NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume we have function which get on input 2D numpy array, matrix, and return product of diagonal elements.
I would like to apply such function to array of matrixes and obtain array of results. Of course, there is naive approach. For instance :

```
def our_func():
    ...

array_of_matrixes = [...]
results = []
for curr_matrix in array_of_matrixes:
    results.append(out_func(curr_matrix))
```

Is there better way of solution in NumPy? I tried to use `.apply_over_axes` and `.apply_along_axis` but they weren’t appropriate.

Comment: Is `array_of_matrices` a list or an array?

Comment: @EricDuminil, numpy array.

Comment: What's the shape of `array_of_matrices`? Could you use a sample `array_of_matrices` and show us the expected output?

Comment: @Divakar, for instance, if we have 10 matrixes of different shape then array_of_matrices.shape = (10,)

Comment: A 1d array of matrices of different shapes is effectively a list of matrices.  Like a list it contains pointers to objects elsewhere in memory.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `np.apply_along_axis` or `np.vectorize` doesn't work reliably is that if your matrices have the same shape, numpy will flatten the array of matrices and will try to apply `our_func` to every single cell in each matrix, which isn't defined.

You could replace

```
results = []
for curr_matrix in array_of_matrixes:
    results.append(out_func(curr_matrix))
```

with:

```
map(our_func, array_of_matrixes)
```

It won't be more efficient, but it's more concise and possibly clearer.

Here's a complete example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix('1 2;3 4')
b = np.matrix('3 1 4;1 2 2;1 3 6')
c = np.matrix('2 1;1 6')
matrices = np.array([a,b,c])
def our_func(m):
    return np.prod(np.diagonal(m))

print(list(map(our_func, matrices)))
# [4, 36, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could make this more concise is using list comprehension:

```
results = [out_func(curr_matrix) for curr_matrix in array_of_matrixes]
```